# running powershell command via ARM template throws "The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet" error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I am trying to execute the following powershell script via Azure ARM template (snippet below),

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD -force

Import-Module -Name AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell -RequiredVersion 2.0.2.89 -force

$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $SecurePassword)
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credentials -Verbose -Debug
```

And getting the following error.

```
{
    "status": "failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "DeploymentScriptError",
        "message": "The provided script failed with the following error:\r\nSystem.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.\nCheck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.\n   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)\n   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)\n   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)\n   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)\n   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)\n   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)\n   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)\n   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)\n   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Boolean propagateAllExceptionsToTop, List`1 variablesToDefine, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, Object[] args)\n   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeUsingCmdlet(Cmdlet contextCmdlet, Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Object[] args)\n   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand.ProcessRecord()\n   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()\n   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()\r\nat <ScriptBlock>, /mnt/azscripts/azscriptinput/removeappregistrationurl.ps1: line 33\r\nat <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1\r\nat <ScriptBlock>, /mnt/azscripts/azscriptinput/DeploymentScript.ps1: line 295. Please refer to https://aka.ms/DeploymentScriptsTroubleshoot for more deployment script information."
    }
}
```

ARM template snippet

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
    "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
    "name": "RemoveAppRegistrationUrl",
    "location": "eastus",
    "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
    "properties": {
        "forceUpdateTag": "1",
        "containerSettings": {
            "containerGroupName": "parsagecustomaci"
        },
        "azPowerShellVersion": "7.2",
        "arguments": "[concat(' -pUid ',parameters('UserId'),' -pPassword ',parameters('Password'),' -appId ',parameters('AppId'), ' -objId ', parameters('ObjectId'), ' -replyUrlToRemove ', parameters('ReplyUrlToRemove'))]",
        "primaryScriptUri": "https://saproliosaasdev.blob.core.windows.net/armtemplates/removeappregistrationurl.ps1",
        "supportingScriptUris": [],
        "timeout": "PT30M",
        "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
        "retentionInterval": "P1D"
    }
}
```

I am able to run the commands from my local powershell instance and Azure cloud shell without any issues.

Comment: Instead of PS New-Object use the Net Library new : [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new($username, $SecurePassword)

Comment: Actually Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credentials -Verbose -Debug is throwing the exception.

Comment: Do you get back a value for credentials (is it null).  You first need valid credentials before connecting.  The original error should of been fixed with my solution.  Now we are trying to fix a second error.

Comment: Kindly check the module : get-module -Name AzureAD
if the module is not installed, make sure that install the module first and try to connect to Azure AD, share the error: if you are getting any error while installing the module.

Comment: credential is not null.  I get the same error if I just execute Connect-AzureAD

Comment: there is no error with Install-Module and Import-Module commands.  it throws error on Connect-AzureAD.

Answer (score 0):

> The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.\nCheck the spelling of the name.

The error message indicates that the **Connect-AzureAD** is not installed on your machine. if the **AzureAD module** is not imported correctly.

You can follow the below steps to troubleshoot the **Azure AD module**.

1. You can verify that the **AzureAD module** is installed correctly by running the following command.

   `Get-Installedmodule | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "AzureAD"}`

[image]

You can also verify the **Connect-AzureAD** cmdlet is present on your system using following command.

```
Find-Command | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "Connect-AzureAD"}
```

[image]

2. If the module is not listed, then you need to install it using the following command

   Install-Module -Name AzureAD

Make sure that confirm the installation by entering **“A” – Yes to All**.

[image]

2. Once you install the module, make sure to import it using the following command

   `Import-Module -Name AzureAD`
3. Update the **AzureAD** module using the following command

   ```
   `Update-module AzureAd`
   ```
4. Once you update the **AzureAD module**, try running the **Connect-AzureAD**.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution this problem? I don't think others realized that you are deploying the via ARM Template and you already have it working on your local PowerShell console.

**You do not need to run 'Connect-AzureAD'** because it is already running in the proper context when deploying it from the ARM Template.

You will however need to install and import the module.  Installing the module seems to work fine, however importing the module will result in a truncating JSON error. I believe this is being caused by loading the module into memory and it consumes the limitation of 2.  I am unsure if the limitation can be altered.

**I think the work around is to use Azure CLI**.  It already supports most Azure AD actions you need. Of course, you will need to do some homework and figure out what those commands are and how to use them. (Assuming you are like me and dont script using it often).

Keep in mind, you will not need to connect using Azure CLI either.  Just run the commands as if you were already connected.

Note:
If you are interested here is [Microsoft Arm Template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.resources/deployment-script-azcli-graph-azure-ad) example.  They are using deployment script to deploy Azure AD objects using Azure CLI in the ARM Deployment script.